# How to check whether certain characters are present in another string which characters are unordered? Using RegEx Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, match, regular-language

How to check whether a string is present on another string in Java, but here the conditions be like:

**For Example:**
    String 1: Panda
String 2: "**a**1**d**22**n**333**a**4444**p**"

Here String 2 needs to have the letter 'p','n','d' at-least once and 'a' at-least twice. Pattern should be matches with the above conditions.

I have done with Regular Expression, but i am not getting the solution.

```
 public static boolean isContainsAnimal(String message,String animal) {
        String animalPattern=generatePattern("panda");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(animalPattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            count++;
        }
        if(count>=1){
            return true;
        }else
        {
            return false;
        }

}
public static String generatePattern(String animal){
    String result="";
    for(int i=0;i<animal.length();i++){
        result+="[^"+animal.charAt(i)+"]*"+animal.charAt(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Suggest me a solution for this problem.

Comment: When experimenting with regular expressions, I often find tools like [Regex101](https://regex101.com) useful, as they give graphical feedback and make it easy to try lots of things quickly. I think this is what your code currently does: https://regex101.com/r/aA1ecJ/2, playing around with your expression there might help you find a working solution yourself.

Comment: Do capital letters matter? In `String 1`, the `P` is capital but in `String 2`, the `p` is lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt does not take account of the different possible orderings of the characters in the `animal` string.  In fact, for a 5 distinct character string, there are 5 factorial different orders.

It is possible to generate a regex with all of the orderings as alternates, but the result is ... horrible and inefficient.

A better idea is to work out if there are letters (like `'a'`) are repeated.  Then generate a regex for each letter, use "match" to apply each one and AND the results.

An even better idea is to not use regexes at all.  They are the wrong tool for this job.